# Error while using actxcontrol in Matlab to clear contents in an open Excel file.

Tags: excel, matlab, com, export-to-excel

This is my code to clear the excel file I have opened.

```
% get running excel file

Excel = actxGetRunningServer('Excel.Application'); 

ExcelFile = Excel.get('Workbooks','usbTC0832.xls');

ExcelSheet = ExcelFile.Sheets.Item('Sheet1');

ExcelFile.Worksheets.Item('Sheet1').Range('A2:C520').ClearContents  

% ExcelFile.Save;
```

Pretty straightforward and it works perfectly in another system. In my new system however it throws up the error

```
>>Error using COM.Excel_Application/get
>>Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception: Invalid index.
```

It works fine the first time right after I restart my system. Every instance afterwords it throws up that error. I've tried restarting matlab but it doesn't go away. I seem to need to restart my system. I can't understand what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you close the connection? Sometimes the file is left open in the background and it gives nasty errors

Comment: No, I'm attempting to access and already open connection with actxGetRunningServer

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the get on Workbooks tries to open the file.
But if it is already open, it will raise an error.
Try to look for it first, with Excel.Workbooks.Item('usbTC0832.xls').
That also could give an error if it is NOT open, you should capture it and if not open, use the get.